# Possibility for exchanging QGIS project files

Tags: geospatial

Is there a site or "Service" to exchange QGIS project files? Perhaps creation of one would be interesting for others.

For example, I have created a complex project for sewer managment. I want to see and compare what others in this field might already have developed to improve my project. But i also want to share my project, because someone else might find it usefull what i have done.

Comment: Why not asking this question on [GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/), where QGIS user used to live. I can assume that sewer management is a bit sensitive topic which not that easily to get information about. And I do not think people will share real working project freely on the web, at least I won't do it due to my company restrictions and policies. However, IMHO you can create an own blog/website/page etc. where you can provide access to such projects.

Comment: Would GitHub/GitLab be a place to share project files? If you choose open geodata/file formats. And for the project files, QGS is just XML: https://github.com/search?q=QGs+extension%3AQGS&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=&l=

Comment: @Taras yeah i guess GIS SE would be the place, but from my experience asking for data there results in a hint to ask for it in the open data SE :)     philshem,GitHub would be possible - a own blog as well. I need to think about what seems best when i have the time! thanks for your input!

Comment: Perhaps give a try contacting the author of this source [QGIS Hub](http://qgis-hub.fast-page.org/?i=1).

Comment: that is looking great! i will message they guy, thanks alot!